# Problema em reconhecer o this.id no jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tenho um código abaixo em JavaScript que pega o `td` que foi clicado e copia para a área de transferência, porém ele não está funcionando. O erro que apresenta no console é:

> (teste).select(); is not a function

O `alert(teste)` retorna o número do `id` certinho. O que eu preciso é copiar esse `id` para área de transferência do clipboard.

```
$("td").click(function(e){
            var teste = e.target.id;
            alert(teste);

            (teste).select();

             document.execCommand('copy');
               alert('Texto copiado para a área de transferência');

        });
```

Comment: Para fazer isso, você precisa colocar o texto em um textarea.

Comment: Crie um textarea pequeno e coloque ele transparente com o css

Comment: Mude para `$(teste).select();`

Comment: Mas mesmo se eu colocar um textarea ele retorn o erro (teste).select(); is not a function

Comment: Eu deixei assim : <td><textarea id="2">teste</textarea></td>

Comment: E meu jquery ficou assim:$("td textarea").click(function(e){
          var teste = $(this).text();
          alert(teste);
          
          $(teste).select();

           document.execCommand('copy');
             alert('Texto copiado para a área de transferência');
      });

Comment: não seria `teste.select();` ??

Comment: teste.select() hugo ele ta erro: .teste.select() is not a function...

Comment: var teste = $(this).text();
          alert(teste);
          
          (this).select();

           document.execCommand('copy');

Comment: Acredito que você precisa copiar o elemento em si e não o valor. Faça como os colegas falaram, copie o texto do TD para o textarea e faça o "var teste = $('#2')", sendo o seu textearea e veja se funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa colocar o texto em uma `TextArea` primeiro, e depois fazer o `.select()` no próprio elemento, e não no valor que será copiado.

Primeiro coloque um TextArea invisível em sua página:

```
<textarea id="texto" style="display:none;"></textarea>
```

Então, na sua function:

```
$("td").click(function(e){
    var valor = e.target.id;        

    $('#texto').val(valor).select();        
    document.execCommand('copy');
    alert('Texto copiado para a área de transferência');
 });
```

Veja outro exemplo [aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_copy_clipboard.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Pode fazer desta forma, sem a necessidade de usar a `id`, usando os objetos [Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createRange) e [Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection) do JavaScript:

```
$("td").click(function(e){
//   var teste = e.target.id;
//   alert(teste);

   var range = document.createRange(); // cria o objeto range
   range.selectNodeContents(this);   // adiciona o conteúdo do elemento clicado
   var sel = window.getSelection();  // cria o objeto Selection
   sel.removeAllRanges(); // limpa o objeto Selection
   sel.addRange(range); // seleciona o texto

   document.execCommand('copy');
   alert('Texto copiado para a área de transferência');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Para obter um id de um elemento especifíco através do jQuery tem uma abordagem um pouco melhor ao invés de usar o event, o que você fazer é pegar através do comando

```
$(this).attr('id');
```

Assim ele vai pegar o elemento clicado no caso this e pegar o atributo id desse elemento.
No caso do .select() você vai ter que pegar ele usando também o $, ficaria mais ou menos isso:

```
$(teste).select();
```

Espero ter ajudado